# Is it possible to make my dialogflow agent to search the internet for an answer to an uncatered question?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Google assistant will search the internet or wiki to questions it did not have an answer for. Is it possible for my agent to do the same too? Rather than saying "Sorry, I don't understand", it will make the agent appear more intelligent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes!

- enable webhook for fallback intent.
- call a search engine API like Google Search or DuckDuckGo(free but limited result).
- parse the service response and create a reply.
- update context as per requirement.
- send the reply back to the user

All this should happen within 5 seconds!

But it would be better to make the conversation agent with the correct use of intents and not overriding the fallback as I just explained. You should follow [best practices](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/best-practices) to develop your agent.